# What is the when.js equivalent of Q.js's "done()"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, when-js

In addition to `then()`, Q.js also has a [`done()`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress). `done()` is usually called at the end of a promise chain, like this:

```
promise
.then(callback)
.then(callback)
.done(callback);
```

This will catch any rejections that were not handled by the previous `then()`s, and it will handle any exceptions raised in `then()`'s callbacks.

Is there something similar in [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when)? How do you handle exceptions raised in callbacks? And what if you never register a rejection handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `when` now has `.done()` as well as `.catch()` and `.finally()`.

See https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#extended-promise-api

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no `done` in `when.js`. Indeed, if you read the last paragraph dedicated to [debugging](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#debugging-promises), there is a mention on a tool called *monitor*, which:

> [...] monitors promise state transitions and then takes action, such as logging to the console, when certain criteria are met, such as when a promise has been rejected but has no onRejected handlers attached to it, and **thus the rejection would have been silent**.

Comment: Alright thanks. I guess I could also use `.otherwise()` to catch stray rejections, but it's not clear from the documentation whether that would also catch any exceptions raised in previously bound callbacks.

Comment: As far as I remember, rejections are passed down the chain of promises. So the answer is yes, it would catch exceptions raised previously.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `done` in when.js.

I advice to request it in their issue tracker, and for a meantime use other library that provides `done`.

Comment: In benchmarks, when.js [is a lot faster](https://github.com/cujojs/promise-perf-tests) than q.js, so losing `done()` might be worth it. Could you recommend another fast library that supports something like `done()`?

Comment: I maintain [deferred](https://github.com/medikoo/deferred) you can check this one, it's fast and has `done` nearly from beginning. I my eyes `done` is a must have for a promise library.